# How do I remove the Windows Explorer Toolbar?

Tags: windows-7

How do I remove the Windows Explorer Toolbar?

[image]

Comment: look what you did. i never had a problem with it till i saw your post. now my OCD has kicked in. thx! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I would try to put the steps here myself, as is normal practice on this site, but in this case, the answer is very detailed, and somewhat complicated, so I will just post the link. It is also EXTREMELY well-done, so I will not try to re-create such a great answer (one of THE best I have ever seen on the Internet).

I would follow this link as it seems to do exactly what you want:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/65416-window-explorer-toolbar-remove.html

Lastly, I would say, make sure you have a good System Restore point AND backup before you try this.

Comment: nice, should i run Remove_Take_Ownership.reg after finishing? (couldnt find any info on the site...)

Comment: I would not think that is necessary.

Comment: Is there way to do this for Classic theme?